# How to pass props to a react component's classname in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-props

I've just started learning NextJS 13 with Tailwind. I'm trying to create a custom banner component that will take in input urls like so:

```
<Banner 
        mobileURL="https://images.michaeltrio.com/banners/2023-10_event_banner_triptojapan_600x720.jpg" 
        tabletURL="https://images.michaeltrio.com/banners/2023-10_event_banner_triptojapan_992x600.jpg" 
        desktopURL="https://images.michaeltrio.com/banners/2023-10_event_banner_triptojapan_1920x640.jpg"/>
```

and set its background image based on the input urls and device like so:

```
export default function Banner({mobileURL="",tabletURL="",desktopURL=""}){
    return (
        <section className={`
            w-full h-[480px] 
            desktop:h-[400px] bg-cover bg-center 
            bg-[url(${mobileURL})] 
            tablet:bg-[url(${tabletURL})] 
            desktop:bg-[url(${desktopURL})]
        `}></section>
    );
}
```

I've created some custom breakpoint tailwind classes and i'm trying to assign different urls to each breakpoint ie set tablet breakpoint to use tabletURL

However, the error message i got was :
"Module not found: Can't resolve './${mobileURL}'"

What did I do wrong, and how do I correct this?

I've tried creating an interface and passing my props that way instead of destructuring like so:

```
interface BannerProps{

    mobileURL:string;
    tabletURL:string;
    desktopURL:string;
}

export default function Banner(props:BannerProps){
    return (
        <section className={`
            w-full h-[480px] 
            desktop:h-[400px] bg-cover bg-center 
            bg-[url(${props.mobileURL})] 
            tablet:bg-[url(${props.tabletURL})] 
            desktop:bg-[url(${props.desktopURL})]
        `}></section>
    );
}
```

But I still get the same error: "Module not found: Can't resolve './${mobileURL}'"
I'm guessing that I'm not using the string literals correctly?